# SQL Inner Join With Sum

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to sum a value with the inner join. There is 4 tables that i´m using the inner join on the another table.

```
Table 1 = mov_estoque
Table 2 = saidas
Table 3 = produtos
Table 4 = movimento
Table 5 = nf
```

On table 1, there is a column `EMPENHO`, data I wanna sum if the column `PRODUTO` is the same.

My code:

```
select m.DATA
      ,n.NOTA
      ,p.COD_PRODUTO
      ,p.DESCRICAO1
      ,p.FATOR_CA
      ,sum(m.EMPENHO) as Total
from mov_estoque as m
inner join saidas as s on m.origem = s.saida
inner join produtos as p on m.produto = p.produto
inner join movimento as t on m.origem = t.cod_operacao
inner join nf as n on s.saida = n.cod_operacao
where m.DATA>'2018-10-01'
and s.filial='3'
and p.tipo_prod='AC'
and (t.evento='21' or t.evento='35')
and m.tipo_origem ='S'
and s.cancelada='F'
and n.cancelada='F'
group by m.produto
order by m.data
```

But this code doesn´t work, I need the sum of empenho based on the produto column.

The output that I need:
http://prntscr.com/l9gk94

```
DATA    NOTA    COD_PRODUTO DESCRICAO1  EMPENHO FATOR_CA    TOTAL
02/10/2018 00:00    164406  900809  SAL DO HIMALAIA FINO (GRANEL 1KG)   -1  1   0
```

Comment: cool story bro. was there a *question*?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: If I was going to attempt to sum something, I feel like I would be tempted to include a sum somewhere.

Comment: `select m.DATA,n.NOTA,p.COD_PRODUTO,p.DESCRICAO1,p.FATOR_CA,SUM(m.EMPENHO) ...`

Comment: @spencer7593 I need to sum the column 'empenho', but this code doesn´t work.

Comment: @Strawberry The sum it´s on the table 'mov_estoque', but i need information that´s on others tables.

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya has provided a truly excellent suggestion

Comment: where is the example data? a sample of expected output?  if you were asking a busy colleague for help, might you consider setting up a demonstration? (e.g. sqlfiddle)

Comment: describing the observed behavior, and how that differs from the expected behavior... describing that as "code doesn't work" is next to useless in terms of diagnosing the problem. Reporting "this code doesn't work" ... that's a *status report*, not a *question*.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @spencer7593 "Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).
"

Comment: @spencer7593 I edited the question and inserted the example, sorry.

Comment: That error message does not look like an error from MySQL. That looks like an error from FirebirdSQL.  (That RDBMS is significantly different from MySQL, some of the suggestions we might give you for MySQL (e.g. modifying sql_mode to remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) wouldn't apply to FirebirdSQL. If you are using Firebird, tag the question with [firebird] not [mysql].)

Answer (score 0):

We can use an inline view to aggregate, to precompute, a total, and then do a join.

For example, we could write a query like this, to get sum of EMPHENHO grouped by produto.

```
 SELECT sm.produto 
      , SUM(sm.EMPENHO) AS sum_empenho
   FROM mov_estoque sm
  WHERE sm.DATA > '2018-10-01'
    AND sm.tipo_origem = 'S'
  GROUP
     BY sm.produto
```

The specification for the total is unclear in the question. This is likely not the total that is desired. But this does demonstrate how we could get a sum, a single row for each value of `produto`.

Assuming that the rest of the query returns the detail rows that we want returned, that is, of we leave off the `GROUP BY` clause and the `SUM` aggregate:

```
 SELECT m.DATA
      , n.NOTA
      , p.COD_PRODUTO
      , p.DESCRICAO1
      , p.FATOR_CA
   FROM mov_estoque m
   JOIN saidas as s on m.origem = s.saida
   JOIN produtos as p on m.produto = p.produto
   JOIN movimento as t on m.origem = t.cod_operacao
   JOIN nf as n on s.saida = n.cod_operacao
  WHERE m.DATA > '2018-10-01'
    AND s.filial = '3'
    AND p.tipo_prod = 'AC'
    AND (t.evento='21' OR t.evento='35')
    AND m.tipo_origem = 'S'
    AND s.cancelada='F'
    AND n.cancelada='F'
  ORDER BY m.data
```

If that gets us the rows we want to return, and we just want to add a "total" column.

Then we could use the first query as a rowsource. Wrap it in parens and reference it the `FROM` clause as an inline view, with appropriate join conditions, and reference the column with the pre-aggregated total in the SELECT list. Something like this:

```
 SELECT m.DATA
      , n.NOTA
      , p.COD_PRODUTO
      , p.DESCRICAO1
      , p.FATOR_CA

      , s.sum_empenho  AS total

   FROM mov_estoque m
   JOIN saidas as s on m.origem = s.saida
   JOIN produtos as p on m.produto = p.produto
   JOIN movimento as t on m.origem = t.cod_operacao
   JOIN nf as n on s.saida = n.cod_operacao

   JOIN ( SELECT sm.produto 
               , SUM(sm.EMPENHO) AS sum_empenho
            FROM mov_estoque sm
           WHERE sm.DATA > '2018-10-01'
             AND sm.tipo_origem = 'S'
           GROUP
              BY sm.produto
        ) s
     ON s.produto = m.produto

  WHERE m.DATA > '2018-10-01'
    AND s.filial = '3'
    AND p.tipo_prod = 'AC'
    AND (t.evento='21' OR t.evento='35')
    AND m.tipo_origem = 'S'
    AND s.cancelada='F'
    AND n.cancelada='F'
  ORDER BY m.data
```